# I am very confused by this and am trying but I don't think I am getting what is wanted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am really confused and need you help I tried but dont think I am getting what I am supposed to

> 5a. (5 pts) Write a function takes an input parameter an integer x,
>   and generates a list of that many 0’s and returns  that list.
>   5b.( 6
>   pts) Now write a function that takes as an input parameter the same
>   integer and, using the first function,  generates a list of x lists of
>   0’s (so you’ll be appending the lists you made in the first function
>   onto your new list.
>
> 5c.(6 pts) Finally, write a third function that
>   loops 5 times. Each time, it generates a first random number (a) 
>   between 0 and x, and then a second random number (b) between 0 and x.
>   It uses those two numbers to change  the list of lists at [a][b] to
>   -1.  You’ve just placed your battleships onto the board (sort of – I know battleships are different lengths. I didn’t want  to complicate
>   this with random length battleships).

```
#5a

def lister(x):
    return([0]*x)

print(lister(15))


#5b

def lister2(x):
    return [lister(x)]*x

print(lister2(3))

#5c

def looplist(x):
    n=5
    a=lister2(x)
    while n>0:
        r1=randrange(0,(x))
        r2=randrange(0,(x))
        a[r1]=-1
        a[r2]=-1
        print(a)
        n-=1

looplist(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do in that final method is:

```
a[r1][r2]=-1
```

You created a bi-dimensional array, so the first part `a[r1]` will get you a list, the one at position [r1], then, on this list, you access position `r2`, and modify the value to `-1`.

Also, I think a simple for will be more readable than your current solution with the while loop:

```
for _ in range(5):
     #generate the two rands, etc
```